# Parent, child JSON parsing in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file with a structure as below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "last_all": {
            "value": "1194999",
            "value_int": "2342",
            "display": "332",
            "disp1": "953.3",
            "current": "BLR"
        },
        "item": "NRF",
        "low": "494.55"
    }
}
```

How would I go about getting the value from "display" from last_all?

This part is where I get stuck: `print $obj['last_all']['display'];` you cant pass more then 3 params so I cant tell PHP to look under data then last_all then display.

Comment: Why can't you pass more than 3 params?  Also that JSON is not valid

Comment: Yeah its not valid cus thats not the full file. I didnt wanna give anything away. Wanna keep my project as confidential as possible. So would I just be able to do print $obj['data']['last_all']['display']; ? Im using json_decode by the way

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer use `json_decode($var, true);`

Comment: Yep thats what im using right now. Still not playing ball unfortunately

Comment: have you tried to use `var_dump($obj)` or `print_r($obj)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple oversight.  You're missing 'data' in your array reference:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string, true);
print $obj['data']['last_all']['display'];
```

Comment: You should not decode JSON as array. Use `$json = json_decode(…);` and then use real properties like `var_dump($json->data->last_all->display);`. The advantage is that you can `json_encode($json)` it back and get the same JSON string representation again. With arrays this won't work.

Comment: @Shi - Why do you believe it won't work with arrays?  An associative array json_encodes to an object, while an indexed array encodes to an array.  It should maintain the same exact json representation as a php object would.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Just try `var_dump(json_encode(json_decode('{ "data": {} }', TRUE)));`. You will get an empty array instead of an empty object.

Comment: @Shi - Ok, in the case of an EMPTY object, I get your point, but then, in JS, empty objects and empty arrays function nearly identically, don't they?

Comment: JSON is not bound to JavaScript. You can use it very well in PHP for configuration files or whatever. An `is_array()` will fail for objects and `is_object()` for arrays.

Comment: @Shi - Good points, all.  Besides the fact that it's just better practice to represent objects as objects.  You've convinced me.  Cheers!